# AUCTeX and XeTeX hiding PDF output

Tags: xetex, emacs, auctex

I'm running AUCTeX 11.88 and TexLive 2014 (I should upgrade), and have so far been using pdfLaTeX exclusively. My AUCTeX have been set up to output PDF files.

My MWE example

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\title{This is a test}
\author{Mathias}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Test}
\label{sec:test}

This is a test!

\end{document}
```

compiles as expected using <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> with pdfLaTeX, and a PDF document is output to the current folder.

However, I am now trying to use XeTeX for my thesis to match a template that produces nice output that matches my university's visual style. When I change the TeX engine (going via `Command->TeXing Options->Use XeTeX engine`), I can compile using XeLaTeX doing <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, and .log/.aux files are created. But no PDF output! The log states that

```
Output written on xetex-test.pdf (1 page).
```

but no such file appears in my folder! I can however press the "Run Viewer" button in AUCTeX and be taken to a compiled PDF document. Running xetex from the command line does create a PDF in the folder.

Where does my PDF file go?

Comment: by default it would go in the current folder, but xetex like pdftex has an `--output-directory` option and if you have configured auctex to use that then the output has gone wherever you sent it:-)

Comment: Wouldn't the --output-directory option send both pdfLaTeX and XeTeX PDF's to the same place? Compiling under pdfLaTeX correctly outputs the PDF to the current folder. Is there somewhere I can find this option? It's not in my .emacs, nor in my `run` call.

Comment: well not if you have configured xetex to use it and not pdftex (honestly if the pdf file isn't in the same directory as the document it coudl be anywhere,   if you are on a unx-like machine `find . -name \*.pdf` shoudl find it